any secrets about his sister
a. Try to make him reveal any secrets about his sister.
b. Try to make him reveal any secrets he knows about his sister.
============
c. They tried to make him reveal any secrets about his sister.
d. They tried to make him reveal any secrets he knew about his sister.
In these sentences does 'any secrets' mean 'all secrets' or 'one or more of the secrets'?
Many thanks.

Any seems superfluous in (a) and (c). We say "I don't know any secrets" but "I know [some] secrets".

If he reveals some secrets, how will the questioner know there are not more that he has not revealed?

He may not know a single secret and there may be no secrets to know. She may be an open book. The torturers are making assumptions.

@TimR - exactly.

If he is a good brother, he will tell them nothing.

In these sentences, "any secrets" means "one or more secrets," rather than "all secrets."

Sentences (a) and (b)  are imperatives.
Adding "knows" in (b) does not change the meaning significantly, as he can only reveal secrets if he actually knows them.
Sentences (c) and (d) are in the past tense.
They describe an attempt to find one or more secrets about his sister.

All the secrets = implies none are left unrevealed.
Any secrets = implies one or more. Typically, "any" is used in questions and negative sentences.
Examples:

"Were the police able to reveal any secrets from the suspect?"
The police weren’t able to make the suspect reveal any secrets."

Edit-1.
Now, let’s consider the difference between using any and all (supposing it’s an official inquiry):

"Try to make him reveal any secrets about his sister.".
Here, it’s not certain that secrets exist, but if they do, they should be revealed.
"Try to make him reveal all secrets about his sister.".
In this case, it’s assumed that some secrets exist, and the instruction is to reveal every one of them.


No, this is wrong. In the cited context, "any" means "all". Same as "The government can demand details of any bank accounts you hold" - that certainly doesn't mean you only have to tell them some of your accounts (saying nothing about the Swiss bank account where you keep all your drug smuggling profits! :) The difference between "any" and "all" in such contexts is just that "any" more explicitly acknowledges the possibility that you may not have any of whatever is being referred to.

@FumbleFingers Point noted. Added it as an edit. OP didn't mention it is a government enquiry.

It's not that "government" or "official inquiry" makes any difference. If a highwayman points his gun at the passengers in a stagecoach and says "Give me any jewelry you have", he means "If you have any jewelry, give it all to me".

@FumbleFingers , "They tried to make him reveal any secrets he knew about his sister"  suggests it is not a magazine interview since it involves a group ("they") working together to get him to reveal information. This phrasing  implies a more intense effort, possibly with some degree of pressure or compulsion,
In contexts like this, "tried to make him reveal" shows a situation where the group is actively pushing him to disclose information, which could hint at an official inquiry or some form of coercion.

You make a lot of assumptions that aren't in the text. (...implies a more intense effort - than what?). At the end of the day it's just an example sentence written by a non-native Anglophone (also posted on a dictionary forum), so it barely even carries its basic literal meaning, let alone embellishments!
